# Set up PiVPN with WireGuard port forwarding issues

Tags: raspberry-pi, vpn, raspberry-pi4, wireguard

I am trying to set up a personal VPN at home using PiVPN and WireGuard, and the installation went fine and everything seems to work and I am even able to connect to the VPN from my mobile device, however I am not getting a connection to the network that I am supposed to be connecting to. I am pretty sure it has to do with the port forwarding and I haven't really been able to figure it out.

[image]

I attatched an image of the port forwarding for my router, I configured the port to be 51820 in PiVPN as that is the port for WireGuard but I'm not sure how to set it up in port forwarding as I have tried several different ways and none of them worked. If anyone can clear up it for me it would be great
Thanks

I've tried setting the IP address to that of the raspberry pi, the 'Source' port and 'Destination' port to 51820 and the 'Forward to port' to 51820 as well, tried to leave 'Forward to Port' same as incoming port.